# Manage Domains of an Azure Web App using C#

Tags: c#, azure, web-applications, dns

I am working on programatically **creating and configuring Azure Web Apps using C#**.

I was already able to create a web app successfully, and have also configured its web hosting plan and upgraded it to "Shared". However, I would like to **add a domain to my web app**.

For example, I would like to add www.examplesite.com to my webapp "TestWebApp".

I have already included using the following NameSpaces in my program:

- using Microsoft.WindowsAzure.Management.WebSites;
- using Microsoft.WindowsAzure.Management.WebSites.Models;

What are the specifics that I need in order to implement this? Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the follow code to manage your domains.

```
using System;
using Microsoft.WindowsAzure.Management.WebSites;
using Microsoft.WindowsAzure.Management.WebSites.Models;
using System.Security.Cryptography.X509Certificates;
using Microsoft.Azure;

namespace updateWebApp
{
    class Program
    {
        private static WebSiteManagementClient _WebSiteClient;
        private static String SubscriptionId = "<your subscription id>";
        private static X509Certificate2 cert = new X509Certificate2("E:/path/azure.cer");
        private static String webspace = "<your webspace name>";
        private static String websitename = "<your web site name>";

        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            var credential = new CertificateCloudCredentials(SubscriptionId, cert);
            _WebSiteClient = new WebSiteManagementClient(credential);

            var web = _WebSiteClient.WebSites.Get(webspace, websitename, null).WebSite;

            web.HostNames.Add("www.example.com");

            var updates = new WebSiteUpdateParameters{
                HostNames = web.HostNames,
                ServerFarm = web.ServerFarm,
                State = web.State
            };

            _WebSiteClient.WebSites.Update(webspaces, websitename, updates);


            System.Console.WriteLine("Press ENTER to continue");
            System.Console.ReadLine();
        }
    }
}
```

This piece of code is just adding the domain "www.example.com" with ssl disable to your web app. In order to use my code, you need to do the following.

1. Create a certificate and upload it to Azure Classic Portal.
2. Create the DNS records, as what is described [here](https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/documentation/articles/web-sites-custom-domain-name/#create-the-dns-records).
3. If you want to have ssl enable, you also need to set up the HostNameSslStates for the WebSiteUpdateParameters. You need the Thumbprint and VirtualIp for this.

Comment: This is amazing! Exactly what I needed. Thank you! I have applied it to my code and it successfully worked. :)

Answer (score 1):

In most cases you do not need to change the code, you need to configure the DNS to direct your users to the correct ip address.

On the following msdn page you can find a walkthrough on how to configure the custom domain name for your site: [web-sites-custom-domain-name](https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/documentation/articles/web-sites-custom-domain-name/)

Comment: Well, OP is specifically asking how to do it programmatically. The link you provided is showing how to do this in Azure Portal. I don't think that is what OP wants.